# Showing all options in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1, layered-navigation

I have a dropdown attibute. It is visible in the layered navigation. But it always shows all the options. Even when one of the options is selected.

I think this is changed from the default setting by our previous web-builder.
I can't ask him anymore. Where do I have to look to change this back?

I have a little experience with Magento, but i can't find it.
Would love your help!

Answer (score 4):

You can start from `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute.php` (it can be rewritten in the local pool or in the custom module)  Note, the magento default function `apply` contains code that hides the options:

```
if ($filter && strlen($text)) {
        $this->_getResource()->applyFilterToCollection($this, $filter);
        $this->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter($this->_createItem($text, $filter));
        $this->_items = array();
}
```